# Cosine series as a Fourier series.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

Theorem:
Let $a_{n}\downarrow 0$ and suppose that $\left(a_{n}\right)$ is a 
      quasi-convex. Then $\displaystyle \frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum a_{n}\cos nx$ is the Fourier series of the $L^{1}$ function $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\Delta ^{2}a_{n}\frac{1}{2} K_{n}(x),
      x\not \equiv 0 \pmod {2\pi} $. Further, $S_{N}(x)\to f(x)$ except at $x\equiv 0 \pmod {2\pi}$, where $\displaystyle S_{N}(x)=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}\cos nx$.

Proof:
 First we see that if $ x \not\equiv 0\pmod {2\pi}$ then
       $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\Delta ^{2}a_{n}\frac{1}{2} K_{n}(x) < +\infty $.

Indeed,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
  \left|(n+1)\Delta ^{2}a_{n}K_{n}(x_{0})\right| &=\left|n+1\right|\left|\Delta ^{2}a_{n}\right|\left|K_{n}(x_{0})\right|\\ &\leq \left|n+1\right|\left| \Delta ^{2}a_{n}\right|\text{cosec}^{2}\frac {x_{0}}{2} \\
&<+\infty \left(\because \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\left|\Delta^{2}a_{n}\right|<+\infty \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$\therefore f(x)$ is well-defined everywhere except at $x\equiv 0\pmod {2\pi}.$

We now show that $f\in L^{1}$.

Let $\displaystyle t_{N}(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{N}(n+1)\Delta ^{2}a_{n}\frac{1}{2}K_{n}(x).$

Now, $t_{N}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ a.e.

$\therefore \left|t_{N}(x)\right| \rightarrow \left|f(x)\right|$ a.e.

By Fatou's lemma,
\begin{equation*}       
\begin{split}
\therefore \frac{1}{\pi}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|f(x)\right|dx               &\leq \frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{N\to\infty} inf \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|t_{N}(x)\right|dx\\
                                                   &\leq \frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{N\to\infty}inf\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{N}(n+1)\left|\Delta ^{2}a_{n}\right|\left|K_{N}(x)\right|dx\\
                                                   &=\frac{1}{2}
                                                   \lim_{N\to\infty}inf \left[\sum_{n=0}^{N}(n+1)\left|\Delta ^{2}a_{n}\right|\right]\\
                                                   &=\frac{1}{2}
                                                  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)\left|\Delta^{2}a_{n}\right| \\      
                                                   &<+\infty .
\end{split}
\end{equation*} 
$\therefore f\in L^{1}$.

We now show that $\|t_{N}-f \|_{1} \rightarrow0$ as $N \to \infty$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\left|t_{N}(x)-f(x)
\right|         &=\left|\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}
(n+1)\Delta^{2}a_{n}\frac{1}{2}K_{n}(x)\right|\\
                &\leq \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\left|(n+1)\Delta^{2}a_{n}\frac{1}{2}K_{n}(x)\right|\\
\therefore \left\|t_{N}-f\right\|_{1} 
                &\leq  \left\|\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\left|(n+1)\Delta^{2}a_{n}\frac{1}{2}K_{n}(x)\right| \right\|_{1}\\
                &\leq\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}(n+1)\left|\Delta^{2}a_{n}
                \right|\frac{1}{2}
                 \rightarrow 0\;{\text {as}}\; N\to\infty.\ (\because \|K_{n}\|_{1}=1.)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
$\therefore \left\|t_{N}-f\right\|_{1} \rightarrow 0$ as $N\to\infty $.

Next we show that $S_{N}(x)\to f(x),$ for $x\not\equiv 0 \pmod{2\pi}.$

Now, $\displaystyle S_{N}(x)=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}\cos nx. $

$\displaystyle \therefore S_{N}(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_{n}b_{n}(x)$ where 
$b_{n}(x)=
\begin{cases}
\cos nx     & ,n\neq0\\
\frac{1}{2} & ,n=0 .
\end{cases}$

Applying partial summation formula twice, we get,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S_{N}(x) &= a_{N}\frac{1}{2}D_{N}(x)+\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\Delta a_{n}\frac{1}{2} D_{N}(x)\\
         &=a_{N}\frac{1}{2}D_{N}(x)+\frac{1}{2}\left[\Delta a_{N-1}N K_{N-1}(x)+\sum_{n=0}^{N-2}\Delta^{2}a_{n} (n+1)K_{n}(x)\right].
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Now for fixed $x\not\equiv 0\pmod {2\pi},\ D_{n}(x)\; \text{and} \; K_{n}(x)$ are bounded sequence of numbers.

Since $(a_{n})$ is convex,
$ N\Delta a_{N}\to 0$ as $N\to \infty $. Also $a_{n}\to 0$.

$\displaystyle \therefore \lim_{N\to\infty} S_{N}(x)=f(x)$.

It remains to show that the series $\displaystyle \frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\cos nx$ is a Fourier series of $f(x)$.

Here $\displaystyle S_{N}(x)=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}\cos nx.$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\therefore \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}S_{N}(x)\cos kx dx
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left[\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_{n}\cos nx\right]\cos kx dx.\\
&=a_{k}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
But $S_{N}(x)\to f(x)$ as $N\to\infty$.

$\displaystyle \therefore a_{k}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos kx dx.$

Now, $\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1) \Delta^{2}a_{n}\frac{1}{2}K_{n}(x),$ which is an even function. ($\because K_{n}(x)$ is an even function.)

$\therefore b_{k}=0.$

Am i right? If i am doing any mistake then please suggest me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should perhaps explain some of your symbols: what's $\,\Delta^2\,$? Or maybe it was meant to be $\,\Delta_{a_n}\,$? What is $\,K_n\,$? Sombody's Kernel (Fejer's, Dirichlet's...)?

Comment: Ok! $$\Delta^{2}a_{n}=\Delta a_{n}-\Delta a_{n+1}.$$ $$K_{n}(x)= \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n} D_{k}(x),$$ which is known as nth Fejer's kernel. And $a_{n}\downarrow 0$ means $a_{n}$ is decreasing and converges to $0$.

Comment: Kns: What happened [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/160611/6179)?